# Mocking httpsession for servlet in junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit

I have servlet which is written below. I need to test the servlet in JUnit. inside the servlet I use `HttpSession` but when I use my test class, it gives an error. How can I mock `HttpSession`?

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

String Product_id = request.getParameter("productID") ;

DB_Con DB = new DB_Con();
Statement smt = DB.getStatement();

if ( session.getAttribute("Username") != null && session.getAttribute("BasketID") != null )
{
    ...
}
```

and my unit test is

```
@Test
public void testStart()  throws IOException, ServletException
{
    AddtoBasket AP = new AddtoBasket();

    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);    
    //HttpSession session = mock(HttpSession.class);
    session.setAttribute("Username", "payam");
    session.setAttribute("BasketID", null);

    when( request.getParameter("productID") ).thenReturn("300");
    //when( request.getSession(true) ).thenReturn(session);


    when( session.getAttribute("Username") ).thenReturn("payam");
    when( session.getAttribute("BasketID") ).thenReturn(null);




    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("somefile2.txt");
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

    AP.doPost(request,response);
    verify(request, atLeast(1)).getParameter("P_code");

    writer.flush(); // it may not have been flushed yet...
    assertTrue(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("somefile2.txt"), "UTF-8")
               .contains("Product Added to basket!"));
}
```

Comment: Uncomment the two commented-out lines in your test, perhaps? Otherwise you'd have to say exactly *what* error you're getting.

Comment: without knowing error , hard to answer . give an error ?? please specify error. Also post full code of `AP.doPost(request,response);`